# Is there any way I can store more attributes with fields/classes in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework-4, custom-attributes

By default Navigation Properties in Entity Frameworks creates properties at both the end of associations, now the problem I am facing is, I want to mark some associations to generate properties at both ends and some to generate only for child of association. Ok I know I can customize the template, but I have no way to store any information inside EDMX editor where I can tell my code generator to skip generating specific navigation property for current class.

I wish there would be something in property pane or I can extend to add some more property in it.

Update:
I know I can abuse documentation property, but I am thinking of some way where I can create Visual Studio Extension (write lots of code using VS SDK) and make it integrate with EDMX editor like we add attached properties in WPF.

Comment: Are you looking for some type of metadata? So as you are parsing your EDMX file you can customize code generation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how deep you want to go, you might find some pointers in [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsimmons/archive/2010/07/12/entityroots-an-ef-extensibility-exercise.aspx) article, which uses the [Entity Data Model Designer Extension Starter Kit](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/DesignerExtStartKit).

Comment: Well thanks for pointing in right direction, let me try if i can make this work or not.

Comment: Your link is old, I think it was under development before VS 2010, everything is now included in VS 2010, there is no such extensibility for UI, however I found annotations that can be used. Thanks for your link.

Answer (score 1):

See this [article](http://blog.ehuna.org/2010/07/microsoft_entity_framework_4_e.html) you can add whatever you want to the EDMX files  ( its just xml ;) ).  He adds an extension property myExtensions:Index so he can generate custom code to do indexing.

Comment: Thanks, I know this, but its kind of little bad, I would be happy if I can make some sort of editor which gives me some visual clue while editing in property browser etc. Or I guess I have to think of making a whole new editor itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could abuse the Documentation property. It is not used in the T4 template (not in the POCO template anyway) so you could put some directives in there.